# Dynamic query preparation and execution in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

In Spark ,this json is in dataframe(DF),now we have to navigate to tables(in json based on cust),we have to read first block of tables & have to prepare sql query.
        Ex:  `SELECT CUST_NAME FROM CUST WHERE CUST_ID =112`

we have to execute this query in Database & store that result in json file.

```
{
     "cust": "Retails",
     "tables": [
        {
             "Name":"customer",
             "table_NAME":"cust",
             "param1":"cust_id",  
             "val":"112",
             "op":"cust_name"
        },
        {
             "Name":"sales",
             "table_NAME":"sale",
             "param1":"country",  
             "val":"ind",
             "op":"monthly_sale"
         }]
}

 root |-- cust: string (nullable = true) 
      |-- tables: array (nullable = true) 
      | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
      | | |-- Name: string (nullable = true) 
      | | |-- op: string (nullable = true) 
      | | |-- param1: string (nullable = true) 
      | | |-- table_NAME: string (nullable = true) 
      | | |-- val: string (nullable = true)
```

same for second block of tables.
        Ex :  `SELECT MONTHLY_SALE FROM SALE WHERE COUNTRY = 'IND'`

have to execute this query in DB & have to store this result as well in above json file.

what is the best approach to do this? any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post the output of df.printSchema?

Comment: root
 |-- cust: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tables: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- param1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- table_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of achieving this. For this whole solution I've used spark-shell. These are some prerequisites:

1. Download this jar from [json-serde](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.keedio.openx.data/json-serde/1.3.7.3/source-code)
2. Extract the zip file to any location
3. Now run spark-shell using this command

   ```
   spark-shell --jars path/to/jars/json-serde-cdh5-shim-1.3.7.3.jar,path/to/jars/json-serde-1.3.7.3.jar,path/to/jars/json-1.3.7.3.jar
   ```

**Your Json document:**

```
{
 "cust": "Retails",
 "tables": [
    {
         "Name":"customer",
         "table_NAME":"cust",
         "param1":"cust_id",  
         "val":"112",
         "op":"cust_name"
    },
    {
         "Name":"sales",
         "table_NAME":"sale",
         "param1":"country",  
         "val":"ind",
         "op":"monthly_sale"
     }]
}
```

**Collapsed version:**

```
{"cust": "Retails","tables":[{"Name":"customer","table_NAME":"cust","param1":"cust_id","val":"112","op":"cust_name"},{"Name":"sales","table_NAME":"sale","param1":"country","val":"ind","op":"monthly_sale"}]}
```

I've put this json in this **/tmp/sample.json**

Now going to **spark-sql** part:

1. Creating table based on json schema

   ```
   sql("CREATE TABLE json_table(cust string,tables array<struct<Name: string,table_NAME:string,param1:string,val:string,op:string>>) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'")
   ```
2. Now load the json data into table

   ```
   sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  '/tmp/sample.json' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE json_table")
   ```
3. Now I'll be using hive lateral view concept [Lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView)

   ```
   val ans=sql("SELECT myCol FROM json_table LATERAL VIEW explode(tables) myTable as myCol").collect
   ```
4. Schema of the returned result:

   ```
       ans.printSchema
       root
        |-- table: struct (nullable = true)
        |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
        |    |-- table_NAME: string (nullable = true)
        |    |-- param1: string (nullable = true)
        |    |-- val: string (nullable = true)
        |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
   ```
5. Result of ans.show

   ```
        ans.show
        +--------------------+
        |               table|
        +--------------------+
        |[customer,cust,cu...|
        |[sales,sale,count...|
        +--------------------+
   ```
6. Now I'm assuming there can be two types of data e.g. ***cust_id*** is of **Number** type and ***country*** is of **String** type. I'm adding a method to identify the type of data based on it's value. e.g.

   ```
   def isAllDigits(x: String) = x forall Character.isDigit
   ```

   **Note:** You can use your own way of identify this

7.Now **query creation based on json data**

```
    ans.foreach(f=>{
val splitted_string=f.toString.split(",")
val op=splitted_string(4).substring(0,splitted_string(4).size-2)
val table_NAME=splitted_string(1)
val param1 = splitted_string(2)
val value = splitted_string(3)
if(isAllDigits(value)){
println("SELECT " +op+" FROM "+ table_NAME+" WHERE "+param1+"="+value)
}else{
println("SELECT " +op+" FROM "+ table_NAME+" WHERE "+param1+"='"+value+"'")
}
})
```

This is the result I've got:

```
SELECT cust_name FROM cust WHERE cust_id=112
SELECT monthly_sale FROM sale WHERE country='ind'
```